# Mapping through array of objects and pulling imgPath for repeated React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, components, mapping

I am trying to display images for an art gallery. I have one MainGallery component and within said Component is a Piece Component being rendered for each object in a helper file portfolio.js

The Piece Component is rendering for each object and I have access to the data from objects but the image path isn'y displaying images even though the file paths are correct.

```
MainGallery.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import portfolio from '../../portfolio';
import Piece from '../Piece/Piece';

export default function MainGallery() {
  // const [pieces, setPieces] = useState(Object.keys(portfolio).map((x) => x));

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(portfolio).map((key) => (
        <Piece
          key={key}
          index={key} // if we need access to key we need to pass it down as prop as something other than 'key'
          details={portfolio[key]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
Piece.js

import React from 'react';

export default class Piece extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // deconstruct properties for Piece
    const { title, imgPath, description } = this.props.details;

    return (
      <div className="single-piece">
        {console.log(imgPath)}
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <img src={imgPath} alt={title} />
        <p>{description}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
portfolio.js

const portfolio = [
  {
    title: 'Storm',
    imgPath: '../../images/storm.jpg',
    description: 'An owl done with ',
    type: 'misc',
    style: 'acrylic',
  },
  {
    title: 'eagle',
    imgPath: '../../images/eagle.jpg',
    description: 'A bald eagle in the wild',
    type: 'pet',
    style: 'paint',
  },
  {
    title: 'family',
    imgPath: '../../images/family.jpg',
    description: 'A portrait of my son and nieces.',
    type: 'people',
    style: 'pastel',
  },
];

export default portfolio;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using require in the src path.

```
<img src={require(imgPath)} alt={title} />
```

If that doesn't work, create a js file in the images folder and export the images like this:

```
export const poster1 = require('./storm.jpg');
```

The third option would be to try to import all the images in your component, but that would require a lot more changes to your code.

```
import storm from '../../images/storm.jpg'
```

and the final thing to try would be to make sure you keep all your images in the public folder instead of src. Then access them like so:

```
<img src='/images/storm.jpg' />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Moving image folder to public folder instead of src did the trick!